# nginx: How can I add headers to both plain HTTP and HTTPS?

Tags: nginx, http-headers

I specified the following in the http-block of /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff always;
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN always;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
```

But now, the headers are only getting added on HTTP requests, not on HTTPS.

Does anyone know how to change this **without** writing it in every single config file?

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header):

> These directives are inherited from the previous level if and only if
>   there are no add_header directives defined on the current level.

The best solution is to place common statements into a separate file, and use an `include` statement.

You can use an `include` statement at the `http` block level and then repeat it in any blocks that need extra `add_header` statements.